# Log the XML content to a file for audit purpose after parsing stream with SAX

Tags: java, xml, stream, xml-parsing, sax

I'm reading XML content via `InputStream` using SAX parser. 
I want to log the XML content to a file for audit purpose after parsing stream (while and before parsing also fine).
But **I want to read the content as a stream** because of performance.
I tried to clone the input stream and process but was not working. Any clue will be highly appreciated.

Code :

```java
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
    
    ////////////////////////////////
    
    SAXParserFactory parserFactor = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = parserFactor.newSAXParser();
    SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler(); // SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler
    
    XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();
    xmlReader.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandlerSax(System.err)); // CustomErrorHandlerSax implements ErrorHandler
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
    
    xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(responseStream)); // responseStream is an InputStream
    // how to log the content that was on the responseStream?
```

Comment: What I would do is wrap the `responseStream` into something that transparently copies the input to an output. Apache commons IO `TeeInputStream` does *exactly* that, so consider it! ([ref](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html)). You will have to deal with the case where there is an error in the einput and parsing stops prematurely - you will probably have to read up to the EOF to finish writing.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a SAX `ContentHandler` that duplicates each event sending it to two different `ContentHandler`s, one being your current one, and the other being a JAXP `TransformerHandler` that serializes the stream of events to a `StreamResult`.